# Is it possible to set tab size in C# console

Tags: c#, console

Is there a nice way to change the tab size in the console?

Normally it is 8 characters long, but it would be good if I could set it to 4 characters.

In the following program I want to list all items of an array with their index. I use the tab to align the text, but there is too much space between the index and the text.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i + ":\t" + myArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why not just use 4 spaces?

Comment: because, when I have for example 10: I only need one space instead of two. I could also insert an if(i>=10) but I hope there is a nicer way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to change the windows cmd tab size. According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key#Tab_characters) it is standardized at every multiple of 8 characters horizontally.

But you can use formatting instead. Your code would look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine($"{i,-4}{myArray[i]}");
```

This would make the `i:` part always four characters wide and fill the right side with spaces if it's less than that. However if your number is four digits it wouldn't add any spaces and you would get output like this:

```
1:  test string
20: test string
300:test string
4000:test string
50000:test string
```

Using tab would still give you space like so:

```
1:  test string
20: test string
300:test string
4000:   test string
50000:  test string
```

If you want to replicate this behaviour you have to use [string padding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/padding) and get the next multiple of 4 based off the length of your `i:` string like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}", $"{i}:".PadRight($"{i}:".Length + (4 - $"{i}:".Length % 4)), myArray[i]);
```

yikes, not as nice...

Comment: There is no need to manually pad the strings like that.  Just use the correct format specifier:  `Console.WriteLine("${i,-4}:{myArray[i]}");`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway do you know of a way to use the format specifier to do the last part of my solution where it would pad to the next multiple of 4?